# How to use IConfiguration object that I built in my Startup class in some other class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are using asp.net core to build our web application. Below is our code which starts the server and passing all the values to underlying classes. This is the way it was designed from starting.

```
public class ProgramApiServer : IWebServer
{
    public void StartServer()
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseKestrel(o =>
            {
                o.Limits.MaxResponseBufferSize = null;
                o.Limits.MinResponseDataRate = null;
                o.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 1000;
                o.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 1000;
                o.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://*:1330")
            .Build();
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my `Startup` class:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("clientsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"clientsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    // building IConfiguration object here
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

// how can I use this in DataProcess class
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    DataProcess.Evaluate(services);
    // ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    // some stuff here
}
```

Below is my `DataProcess` class:

```
public static class DataProcess {

    public static void Evaluate(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        Process(services, ....);
    }

    private static void Process(IServiceCollection services, ....) 
    {
        // ...

        // here I need to use IConfiguration object to get value for my config
        Console.WriteLine(_configuration["configKey"]);
    }
}
```

**Question:**

As you can see above I am calling `Evaluate` method of `DataProcess` class from `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup` class. I need to use `IConfiguration` object in `Process` method of `DataProcess` class but I am not able to figure it out on how can I use it.

I recently started working with asp.net and trying to see on how can I pass around the `IConfiguration` object cleanly to my static `DataProcess` class. Is it a good idea to pass it via `Evaluate` method in `Startup` class and then store it in global variable in `DataProcess` class that can be used in `Process` method or any other better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just pass it through your `Evaluate` method to your `Process` method?

```
public static class DataProcess {

    public static void Evaluate(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        // ...
        Process(services, configuration, ....);
    }

    private static void Process(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration, ....) 
    {
        // ...

        // here I need to use IConfiguration object to get value for my config
        Console.WriteLine(configuration["configKey"]);
    }
}
```

And in your `Startup.cs` just call it with required params:

```
DataProcess.Evaluate(services, this.Configuration);
```

Comment: I can do that for sure but I just wanted to make sure if this is the right way to do it or there is any other better way to achieve that.

Comment: _there is any other better way to achieve that_ - can you define 'better' more exactly here?

Comment: when I say better I mean in terms of asp.net fundamentals. I am pretty new to asp.net so thought instead of passing like this in a method, there must be a way by which I use `IConfiguration` object globally instead of passing it around like this. Just wanted to understand nothing else.

Comment: If it weren't a static class you would be able to inject it through a constructor using DI and bind it to one of your fields in order to use it across multiple methods. The only other thing I can think of here is to build a `ServiceProvider` out of `IServiceCollection` and call `GetService<IConfigurationRoot>` method in order to resolve the registered instance of that type which would then give you the access to its properties, but I think this is much simpler thing to do.

Comment: ok thanks @msmolcic got it now. I will go with your current suggestion where I can pass around `IConfiguation` object to my method and then use it. thank you!